# The fact that something lasts or will last a lot of time

Tags: single-word-requests, nouns

I'm looking for a single word that expresses **the fact that something lasts through the passing of years, decades, centuries**.

What would be a word that describes the art of lasting?

From my mother language, "persistence" is what Google Translate comes up with, but I am dissatisfied.

Current contenders:

- [Perenniality](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/perenniality?s=t) (from perennial)

  > lasting for an indefinitely long time; enduring
- [perdurability](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/perdurability?s=t) (from perdurable)

  > very durable; permanent; imperishable.

Comment: It might be helpful if you added a sentence where this noun could be used.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[**Permanence**](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/permanence) is the characteristic of lasting indefinitely or without changing.

[**Imperishability**](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/imperishable?q=imperishability#imperishable__6) is the characteristic of enduring forever.

[**Durability**](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/durability) is the resilience or robustness that enables something to last for a long time.

(Links to definitions at Oxforddictionaries.com)

Answer (score 2):

[Endurance](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/Endurance) conveys the concept you are describing:

> - lasting quality; duration.

[enduring](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/Enduring) :

> - Lasting; continuing; durable: a novel of enduring interest.

( from TFD)

Comment: I think endurance also implies that there are negative factors all around, doesn't it?

Comment: It suggests that something lasts despite the pros and cons.

Comment: Is there maybe a word that does not imply the presence of negative factors?

Comment: Why do you think "endurance" implies negative factors?

Comment: You are asking for 'the art of lasting', and that implies the ability to survive in any (favourable or unfavourable )situation.

Comment: @brasshat in the majority of definitions of endurance:  the ability to do something difficult for a long time

: the ability to deal with pain or suffering that continues for a long time

: the quality of continuing for a long time

Comment: I guess it's all in the point of view of the beholder. I don't consider the ability to do something difficult for a long time, nor the ability to deal with pain or suffering, a negative thing; nor is a negative sense required for something to endure. Psalm 119 of the Hebrew and Christian Scriptures, for example, proclaims that the faithfulness of God endures throughout all generations. [NB in some numbering systems Psalm 119 is numbered 118.]

Answer (score 1):

How about abides? As in "People come and go but the earth abides."
See Websters: http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/abides

Comment: what does abide mean? Pls add relevant reference to tour answer!!

Comment: Try websters? http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/abides

Comment: You should edit that into your answer instead of posting it as a comment.

Answer (score 0):

*everlasting*

adjective: 
1.lasting forever or for a very long time.

synonyms:eternal, endless, never-ending, perpetual, undying, abiding, enduring, infinite, boundless, timeless. 
antonyms:   transient, occasional.

noun:

1.the everlasting; plural noun: everlastings; noun: everlasting flower; plural noun: everlasting flowers

2.literary: eternity.
3.a flower of the daisy family with a papery texture, retaining its shape and color after being dried, especially a helichrysum.

please see: [everlasting](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/everlasting) (TFD)

Comment: is there a noun form of this?

Answer (score 0):

Somewhat surprisingly, [*eternality*](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/eternality) ("the quality or state of being eternal") turns out to be a recognized word; the *OED* records it in use as early as the 15th century, and I believe that it would be readily understood by most people, in addition to being evocative enough to make an impression.